# Orchard Navigation - how to make menu link not clickable

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have following menu navigation:

```
home
product
     product 1
     product 2
news
     press releases
about us
```

Every menu item above links to a Content, except "product".I need to make it so when the user click "product" would not go anywhere.

I tried to use "Custom Link", and enters "#" or "javascript:void(0)" in the url, however that does not work since Orchard always prefix the url with "/".

Also, I tried to use "Html Menu Item" and enter "product" in the html body, but always rendered as

```
<li><span class="raw"><p>product</p></span><ul>...</ul></li>
```

I want either following:

```
<li><a href="#">product</a><ul>....</ul></li>
```

or

```
<li>product<ul>....</ul></li>
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Menu.cshtml` file under the `Core->Shapes->Views` directory in the `Orchard.Web` project, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Nav a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The above disables clicking on all of your menu links, so if you want to prevent clicking on the second level menu items:

```
$('#Nav li ul li a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

That `Menu.cshtml` file is the view for your navigation menu, so you can define it's behavior as you wish there. You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938655/customizing-the-orchard-navigation-menu) of mine as well.

Answer (score 4):

You may do as Mohammad says, but create an alternate Menu.cshtml in your Theme. It is bad practise to modify Orchards core code.

Comment: You're correct, creating an alternate is the way to go but I wanted to spare having to explain shape tracing and alternates. Nevertheless they are indispensable skills for any Orchard developer and need to be learnt at some point.

Comment: I am familiar with url alternates and shape tracing - but wants to avoid doing it, because the project is already publish to PROD (Azure), hence accepted the jquery work around above. At least I can just copy .js file rather than doing another deployment. Up vote anyway.