# Customizing the entire markup for the orchard cms navigation zone

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I've been searching high and low for the past couple of days for the file(s) in Orchard where I can customize the markup used for the navigation

Traversing the tree in the Designer Tool and looking at the template and HTML views doesn't help much seeing as the `MenuItemLink` renders the `<li>` in the HTML view but nothing renders it in the template view. So I am quite stumped.

The original markup is like so (Taken from the Designer Tools `Zone [Navigation]`):

```
<div class="zone zone-navigation">
    <article class="widget-navigation widget-menu-widget widget">
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu menu-main-menu">
                <li class="first">
                    <a href="/Orchard/work">Work</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </article>
</div>
```

What I need is to customize the classes on the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements, really.
If possible I'd love to be able to customize it all so I didn't need the `<div class="zone zone-navigation">` for example.

But is this even possible?

Comment: have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076340/orchard-navigation-how-to-make-menu-link-not-clickable) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938655/customizing-the-orchard-navigation-menu)?

Comment: Yes, none of your answers explains how to access the `<li>` element, although they are very informative :)

Comment: If you try doing what I've explained there, you will stumble upon how `<li>`s are rendered. Just under the `Menu.cshtml` there is a `MenuItem.cshtml` that you could modify.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I had stared at it for too long!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `<li>` element is rendered by `MenuItem` shape (`Core\Shapes\MenuItem.cshtml`)
- `<nav>` and top `<ul>` elements are rendered by `Menu` shape
  (`Core\Shapes\Menu.cshtml`)
- `<a>` element is rendered by `MenuItemLink` shape (`Core\Shapes\MenuItemLink.cshtml`)

If you want to override the defaults, simply put appropriate `Menu.cshtml`, `MenuItem.cshtml` or `MenuItemLink.cshtml` files in your theme (or better - copy the default one(s) and alter). Those will be used then instead of the default ones I wrote about above.